# excel vba internet explorer automation - access input inside two divs

Tags: excel, vba, mshtml

First time doing this.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="program-filters">
   <span>Search</span>
   <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <input role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" autocomplete="off" value="SEARCH VALUE HERE">
   </div>
   <a class="in-map-btn btn btn-primary btn-go btn-mobile-fixed">GO</a>
</div>
```

And based on [this code](http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com.au/2018/02/vba-ie-createevent-and-dispatchevent-to.html#focusTip) I am trying to access the `input` in my `vba`. The `input` has a `role` but no `id` or `class`. The structure in `jQuery` would be

```
`$('.program-filter input);`
```

My `vba` code to access the input is:

```
Do
    '* wait for the input box to be ready
    Set HTMLtags = oHtml.querySelector(".program-filters").getElementsByTagName("div").getElementsByTagName("input")
    DoEvents
Loop While HTMLtags.Length = 0
```

But it fails with `Object does not support this property or method` at line:

```
Set HTMLtags = oHtml.querySelector(".program-filters").getElementsByTagName("div").getElementsByTagName("input")
```

How do I access the `input`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With querySelector you can access combobox in this way:

```
oHtml.querySelector(".program-filters input[role='combobox']")
```

The following will not work in VBA:

```
.getElementsByTagName("div").getElementsByTagName("input")
```

You can get a collection of elements based on a single element, for example `.getElementsByTagName("div")(0)`, not another collection.

Here is a working example of the code. On my end I can use `Debug.Print inputBox.Value`, because combobox is pre-populated:

```
Option Explicit

Sub get_data()

    Const myURL As String = "http://play.afl/club-finder/?"

    Dim inputBox
    Dim appIE As Object
    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With appIE
        .Navigate myURL
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Do While appIE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Set inputBox = appIE.document.querySelector(".program-filters input[role='combobox']")
    Debug.Print inputBox.Value        

    appIE.Quit
    Set appIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Ryszard Jędraszyk thanks for the suggestion. I have been away for 2 days so sorry for late reply. Your suggestion fails with `Type mismatch`.

Comment: I have updated an answer with an example which works on my end.

Comment: @TheRealPapa `Type mismatch` on which line?